# No internet access on guest SSID on Netgear WNR2000 router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have a WNR2000v2 Netgear router that I want to put on our company's network.  My boss wanted me to set up two SSIDs, one is for guests and the other is for employees.  He wanted the guest wireless account configured for internet access ONLY, which means that any guests connected to this SSID should not be able to see any company computers.

I've never configured a router this way so I did some research and found out that since my company's network already has a DHCP server and a gateway that I have to disable DHCP on the router and plug the ethernet cable connected to my gateway into one of the LAN ports, NOT the WAN port.

I did this and entered the IP addresses of my company's gateway, DHCP servers, and DNS servers.  Then I setup the two SSIDs and I restarted the router.  First, I connected to the Non-Guest SSID, it connected without a problem and gave my computer a company IP address (10.***.**.132, not a 192.168.1.*** address) and I had internet access.  I took this as a good sign because it tells me that my companies DHCP server is assigning the IP address, not the router.

Then I tried connecting to the Guest SSID.  I was able to connect to the SSID and it gave me a company IP address, but I was not able to get internet access.

Since I've never set up a guest WIFI SSID like this before I'm not sure where to go from here.  Is what I'm trying to do possible with this router?  I would like to set it up so that computers connected to the guest SSID can access the internet.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use the router as an access point (“put it on the network”). In that case, the guest network mode will not work. It relies on the fact that the router does the routing, which is not the case in AP mode.

Answer (score 0):

Alright your problem can be broken down into two main things here.

1. You need clients to have company access on a secure SSID
2. You need guests to only have internet access on an open SSID

Now, for the first problem, you need to set up the router so that all DHCP requests are forwarded to your DHCP server. These clients need to behave as if they were plugged into the network. Your DHCP server must be involved because they are usually interfaced with AD & DNS. It sounds like you've already managed to do this. This should be placed on your company VLAN so the traffic is treated as such.

For, your second problem, these clients should behave as if they originated in a DMZ (De-Militarized Zone). They should have no company access, and only able to access internet exterior to your network. Typical implementations would have you create a separate VLAN for these clients so their DHCP requests are responded to **ONLY** by a DHCP server that handles this type of thing. If you already have a DMZ DHCP server then set it up to listen to that VLAN (If you have a webserver it can sometimes be serviced by this). If you have only one DHCP server that handles both, you need to make sure it can differentiate and assign addresses to that VLAN and that all traffic is routed/switched through this DMZ with no access to the company VLAN.

I know this may look complicated, but this is the necessary steps to have the traffic entirely differentiated from each other.